# Getting the error message "assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast" while trying to write a parsing program

Tags: c

I'm trying to write a parsing program that will read the file /proc/stat and store its various tokens in arrays. This is the progress I have made so far. my problem comes with the line

```
s = strtok(str, " ");
```

With this line I get the error message:
    ass2.c:62:15: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
             s = strtok(string, " ");

I'm not sure how to solve this issue. I'm just about a complete beginner with C so not familiar with the feedback terms and so I'm struggling to rectify this issue. Below I have pasted the entire programs code so far.

```
//standard input/output file to help with io operations
#include<stdio.h>
//standard library files to help with exit and other standard functions
#include<stdlib.h>
//header file for usleep function
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
//FILE pointer will need to be declared initially, in this example the name     is fp
FILE *fp;
//A character pointer that will store each line within the file; you will need to parse this line to extract useful information
char *str = NULL;
//size_t defined within C is a unsigned integer; you may need this for getline(..) function from stdio.h to allocate buffer dynamically
size_t len = 0;
//ssize_t is used to represent the sizes of blocks that can be read or written in a single operation through getline(..). It is similar to size_t, but must be a signed type.
ssize_t read;
int cpu_line1[5];
int cpu_line2[5];
int cpu_line3[5];
int cpu_line4[5];
int cpu_line5[5];
int page_line[3];
int swap_line[3];
int intr_line[2];
int ctxt_line[2];
int btime_line[2];


//a variable declared to keep track of the number of times we read back the file
unsigned int sample_count = 0;

//opening the file in read mode; this file must be closed after you are done through fclose(..); note that explicit location of the file to ensure file can be found
fp = fopen("/proc/stat", "r");

//checking if the file opening was successful; if not we do not want to proceed further and exit with failure code right away
if(fp == NULL)
{
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
int i = 0;
char **string = NULL; //declaration of string
string = (char**)malloc(10*sizeof(char*)); //assign space for 10 pointers to array
for (i=0; i<10; i++) //allocate 50 bytes to each string in the array
{
    string[i] = (char*)malloc(50*sizeof(char));
}


//a loop that will read one line in the file at a time; str will read the line; len will store the length of the file
while(sample_count < 1)
{
    printf("\e[1;1H\e[2J"); //this line will make sure you have cleared the previous screen using C's powerful format specifiers
    printf("----------------------------------------------------------------\n");//used for presentation
    printf("Sample: %u\n", sample_count); //showing the sample count

    while ((read = getline(&str, &len, fp)) != -1)
    {
        printf("Retrieved line: \n%sof length: %zu, allocated buffer: %u :\n", str, read, (unsigned int) len);
        //You will then need to extract the useful information, including the name and the statistics
        char *s = NULL;
        s = strtok(str, " ");
        sprintf(string[i], s);
        printf("Test: %s", string[0]);

    }

    if (i=0)
        {
            cpu_line1[0] = atoi(strtok(NULL, " "));
            cpu_line1[1] = atoi(strtok(NULL, " "));
            cpu_line1[2] = atoi(strtok(NULL, " "));
        }

    printf("----------------------------------------------------------------\n"); //used for presentation
    usleep(500000);//this will ensure time delay
    rewind(fp);//rewind the file pointer to start reading from the beginning
    sample_count++;//update the sample count
}
//once you are done, you should free the pointers to make your program memory efficient
free(str);
//once you are done, you should also close all file pointers to make your program memory efficient
fclose(fp);


return 0;
```

}

Comment: `#include <string.h>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you did not `#include` the header file in which `strtok` is declared, the compiler assumes that the return type of the function is `int`. Hence, the warning.

Add

```
#include <string.h>
```

to fix the problem.